# Split strings using regular expression and evaluate it

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which contains some variable , arithmetic and logical operators. My Problem statement is to substitute the value of the variable and evaluate it and send True or False

My String:

```
'ABC >= 55 and Xyz <= 5500 or ABCDe == 900 or xYz == 30'
```

Here , ABC , Xyz and ABCDe are dynamic it can be anything. I need to get the value of those variable from str1 and evaluate like this below

```
eval( 100 >= 55 and 555 <= 5500 or 50 == 900 or 10 == 30)
```

I have tried the following things,

```
def replace(match):
    return '{}'.format(10)

re.sub(r'[a-b|A-Z]\w+',replace, str1)
```

Output :

```
'10 >= 55 10 10 <= 5500 or 10 == 900 or x10 == 30'
```

Problem here is it replacing 'and','or' also replacing is not proper it replaced `xYz as x10` 
Then i tried replacing those with special characters

```
>> str2 = str1.replace('and', '&').replace('or', '|')

>> print str2
>> ABC >= 55 & Xyz <= 5500 | ABCDe == 900 | xYz == 30

>> re.sub(r'[a-b|A-Z]\w+',replace, str2)
```

It solved the replacing of operators but not the case sensitive problem

```
'10 >= 55 & 10 <= 5500 | 10 == 900 | x10 == 30'
```

Could someone help me in this...or any other way to this?

Comment: I'm struggling a little with the explaination of what you're trying to do, my first question would be are you trying to use `=` or `==`? the latter will return true/false where the former will assign the variable ABCDe to be 900

Comment: Yes.It will be ==

Comment: How do you know which variables have which values? You must have a list of variables somewhere, right? Can you walk over that list and replace the specific variables instead of using a regular expression to find all word-like strings?

Comment: Those variables are present either in db or in some property file which will read using `def replace(match):  return '{}'.format(10)` Instead of `format(10)` i will call and fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see is your replace function is always returning 10:

```
return '{}'.format(10)
```

will always return 10 so that is why your string is not right.

Another thing I see is that you're not indicating which value goes to which dynamic variable.

I was able to solve the issue with the following code: (quickly and crudely type)

```
import re

rep_hash = {
    r'ABC\b' : '100',
    r'Xyz\b' : '555',
    r'ABCDe\b' : '50',
    r'xYz\b' : '10'
}

str1 = 'ABC >= 55 and Xyz <= 5500 or ABCDe == 900 or xYz == 30'
str2 = ''
for item in rep_hash:
    str1 = re.sub(item, rep_hash[item], str1)

print str1
```

the \b makes it an exact match so that ABC wont match ABCDe

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am always returning `return '{}'.format(10)` just as a place holder to replace it. Actually i will call some other implementation to fetch those values.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `my_string = 'ABC >= 55 and Xyz <= 5500 or ABCDe == 900 or xYz == 30'`. I'm going to assume this string is supposed to be a valid Python expression.

I assume you have a dict called variable_values:

```
variable_values = {'ABC': 10, 'Xyz': 555, 'ABCDe': 50, 'xYz': 10}
```

You must have something of the sort because otherwise you wouldn't know what to substitute.

Step 1. Substitute the values for the variable names. You can't do this simply by using `string.replace()` because if you have two variables `ABC` and `ABCABC`, and `ABC` has the value `100`, then doing a naive replace is going to substitute the value `100100` for `ABCABC` which is probably not correct. So insist that the variable name must begin and end with a word_boundary.

```
for name, value in variable_values.items():
    my_string = re.sub(fr"\b{name}\b",str(value),my_string)
```

Step 2. Now `my_string` has the value `'10 >= 55 and 555 <= 5500 or 50 == 900 or 10 == 30'`. Call `eval()` on it.

```
>>> eval(my_string)
False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a string not as a dict.`my_string = 'ABC >= 55 and Xyz <= 5500 or ABCDe == 900 or xYz == 30'` . From this string i have extract out the variables ABC , Xyz , ABCDe , ..or it can be any. Assume it like an user input.

Comment: I know that. If you look at the answer, you will see that `my_string` looks exactly like that. But `ABC` is supposed to have the value `10`, right? That value `10` has to come from somewhere. You didn't say where you are getting it. A `dict` is the obvious solution for that.

Comment: `my_string` is exactly the same string which i need to evaluate but `variable_ values` i need to fetch from database by passing the extracted variable name from the input string and get the value and replace it. eg. `get_value('ABCDe')`

Comment: Ah. That was not clear. You didn't say anything about a database. In that case you're going to have to do a proper parse on the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow made it worked with below.

```
def replace(match):
    return '{}'.format(10)

my_string = 'ABC >= 55 and Xyz <= 5500 or ABCDe == 900 or xYz == 30'

string2 = my_string.replace('and', '&').replace('or', '|')

eval(re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]\w+\b',replace, string2))
# False
```

Is there any better and efficient way to do it